# Reading gps ports data using java

Tags: java, sockets, gps, port

I need to read data from a GPS device ports, and I want to decode that data back to an original format. The data I will be getting is in Hexadecimal format, and I want to convert it into a String format. How can I continuously get data without any complexity? Please anybody give me a hint on how to do that. I am very new to it, please explain it to me.

Comment: Hexadecimal is not a format, it is a format representation. You need to know the format/protocoll, which is either NMEA or the chip manufacturers binary protocoll. (Sirf Binary or ublox binary for manufacturers Sirf and ublox). First find out to what format the output if the GPS chip is set.

Comment: Further about: "without any complexity": Software developping always has some complexity.

Answer (score -1):

Use [gpsd](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/) and talk to it over its JSON interface.

Comment: If u don't maid could u plz exp line me with brief code...I am very new to it.....

Comment: @user2968238 I know it's not you; you don't have the rep to downvote yet. But this is the sanest answer you are going to get (GPS is *nasty*, and even gpsd, which is the closest thing to a decent decoder that exists, has some really scary unioned structed bitfields), and drive-by downvoting is obnoxious.